# If string entered into input matches it reveals an HTML element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function

I currently have the following code. When a string entered into the input field of "#gotthekey" matches the value in the code it reveals a div element called "codebox".

My question is how could I get this to work for multiple strings e.g. "1234" "4231", "2341"...etc? Do I need to utilise an array of some sort?

Your help would be mich appreciated, my experience with js at the minute is limited.

```
<code>
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j("#gotthekey").keyup(function() {
            if (this.value == "1234567890") {
                $j(".codebox").css({'display' : 'block','float' : 'left','margin-left' : '16%'
                });
                $j(".gotthekey").css("display", "none");
                }
            else {
                $j(".codebox").css("display", "none");
                $j(".gotthekey").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    });
</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the strings into an array and use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (['1234', '4231', '2341'].includes(this.value))
```

Comment: Be cautious though as not many browsers support `Array.prototype.includes` yet

Answer (score 1):

you can put all the strings in an array "arr" and use arr.indexOf(val) to see if the value matches any of the strings

Answer (score 0):

Put strings you want to check into array.

Use: `arrayOfStringsToCheck.includes('string')` returns true or false

Answer (score 0):

Good approach in your code will be to replace

```
 if (this.value == "1234567890")
```

with something

```
 if (checkValue(this.value))
```

and your checkvalue can use `set` for better performance

```
checkValue(val) {
    const stringSet = new Set([1234, 4321, 2134]);
    return stringSet.has(val)
}
```

more on set : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: Thanks guys, really appreciate the expertise. Once stored in the array/set how would I use the result to reveal a hidden div element? This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: The above function will return Boolean and if value is found then your code should execute and  show codebox as it is working now

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for so thanks Shadab. The only thing is I'm gettting an unexpected token error in the set you suggested above and I can't see what is causing this. Apologies for my noobness!